# How do i prove this problem with a product and its fraction part?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

How do I prove that $\forall \:\:r\:\in \mathbb{R}$,$\:r\:>\:1,\:\sum _{i=0}^n\:xr^i=x\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$.

Comment: What does $x$ represent?

Comment: a constant i guess?

Comment: Ok; at first I saw it one on side of the equation and not the other and that didn’t make sense but after an edit it appears on both sides now

Comment: sorry for that.:)))

Comment: These are terms of a [geometric series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Comment: Try multiplying both sides by $1-r$

Comment: Do i need to cancel x?. i got r^i - r^2i = 1 - r^n. What should i do next?

Comment: If $x=0$ the statement is true, and otherwise divide both sides by $x$

Comment: You had a typo in the equation which i corrected. The exponent should be $n+1$ instead of $n$

Comment: When you multiply the left side by $1-r$ and shift the index of one of the sums you should get a [telescoping series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Comment: Difficult to put in a comment, so I posted it as an alternative answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing off my phone here. Let’s prove it by induction. 
It is obviously true for $n=1$ (base case)

Assume the equation you have is true at $n-1$, namely

$\:r\:>\:1,\:\sum _{i=0}^{n-1}\:xr^i=x\frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}$

Now let’s prove it for $n$

$\sum _{i=0}^{n}\:xr^i=\underbrace{x\frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r} }_{\sum _{i=0}^{n-1}\:xr^i}+xr^n=x\frac{1-r^{n} + r^n -r^{n+1}}{1-r}= x\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r} $

Comment: If you’re proving by induction, then you also need to prove the base case

Comment: Yes @J.W.Tanner typing off a phone here :)

Comment: is the base case the one we assumed is true? why did we add xr^n to the original problem?

Comment: @Sign i have edited, please check now

Comment: thank you very much for the help. appreciated it a lot. it's clearer now.

Comment: Welcome @Sign 

Answer (score 0):

$(1-r)\sum_{i=0}^n xr^i = \sum_{i=0}^nxr^i - \sum_{i=0}^nxr^{i+1} = \sum_{i=0}^nxr^i-\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}xr^{i}$

$=xr^0+\sum_{i=1}^nxr^i-\sum_{i=1}^nxr^i-xr^{n+1}=x(1-r^{n+1}).$

Divide both sides by $1-r$ and you're done.